# How read from 2 Azure Service Buses in different regions and treat it as one

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have nearly identical service buses in 2 separate regions.  I am trying to make them be more region agnostic for consuming applications.

While looking into things like Azure [service bus geo-disaster recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr) and [message replication and cross-region federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-federation-overview) and how complicated they are, I was thinking instead that I could create a service bus client that would just read from the same topic/subscription name in separate regions and treat them as if they came from the same region.

While I'm sure this can be implemented, I was wondering, does this functionality exists in any current Microsoft libraries?  Basically, if message A get published to the east topic/subscription and message B gets published to the Central US topic/subscription, then the client would receive A and B.  The order is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of functionality has existed in the track 0 SDK of Azure Service Bus SDK for failover but not concurrent execution. As it was a client-side feature, it did not get much traction and was very confusing and complicated.

NServiceBus had a legacy Azure Service Bus transport that supported using more than one namespace concurrently. The feature was deprecated as it was also more of a trouble than good. Not to mention the fact that Service Bus has introduced the Premium tier which would handle availability better than multiple standard namespaces together. On top of that, add availability zones and it's hands down a better option than the complexity of setting up multiple receivers.

In case your namespaces are identical, I would suggest consolidating them. One of the strategies would be to "forward" messages from one namespace to another using some processor as there's no cross-namespace forwarding.